# Given that the marble drawn is yellow, find the probability that is was originally from jar A.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Jar A has 5 yellow and 8 green while jar B has 2 yellow and 6 green marbles. Two marbles are transferred from jar A to jar B and then one marble is taken from jar B.

a) Find the probability that marble drawn from jar B is yellow.

b) Given that the marble drawn is yellow, find the probability that is was originally from jar A.

I got part a correct, answer is $\frac{18}{65}$. However, my part b is wrong.

What I did for part b:

P(yellow from A | yellow)
= $\frac{\text{P(yellow and it is from A)}}{\text{P(yellow)}} $

Numerator: P(yellow and it is from A) = $\frac{5}{13}$ $\times$ $\frac{4}{12}$ $\times$ $\frac{2}{10}$ +  $\frac{5}{13}$ $\times$ $\frac{8}{12}$ $\times$ $\frac{1}{10}$ $\times$ 2

Denominator: P(yellow) = $\frac{18}{65}$

And I got $\frac{5}{18}$.

But the correct answer is $\frac{55}{234}$. May I ask what did I do wrong?

Comment: FWIW I am also getting $\frac {5}{18}$.  My method: fixing one of the yellow balls that starts in $B$, we see that there is a $\frac 1{10}$ chance that it is drawn.  Thus there is a $\frac 15$ chance that the yellow ball came from $B$, so the answer is $\left(\frac {18}{65}-\frac 15\right)\big/ \frac {18}{65}=\frac 5{18}$.  Just to give an alternate computation.

Comment: Yes even I get $\frac{5}{18}$.

Comment: Yes, also $5/18$ here by drawing a tree diagram